# HttpUtility.UrlEncode in C# Translates to What on the server?

Tags: c#, encoding, decoding

I have a string that I am trying to pass from my C# app to my ASP.NET MVC 3 endpoint. This string looks like the following

```
(2+3=5)/20
```

I am using the HttpUtility.UrlEncode method to prepare the data. I've noticed that the resulting string looks like the following:

```
(2%2b3%3d5)%2f20
```

This value is getting passed back to an ASP.NET MVC 3 endpoint. I know that the endpoint looks like the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UploadData(string data)
{
  // What does "data" look like here? Does it look like (2+3=5)/20 or, (2%2b3%3d5)%2f20
}
```

I'm trying to understand what data will look like on the server when its passed back. If the variable on the server is used WITHOUT any manipulation, will it be (2+3=5)/20 or (2%2b3%3d5)%2f20?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does "data" look like here? Does it look like (2+3=5)/20 or, (2%2b3%3d5)%2f20

It looks like this: `(2+3=5)/20`. ASP.NET takes care of url decoding properly url encoded query string parameters.